# ADF DATA FLOW NULL Column

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am inserting records into a table where a column called TenantID is not nullable. I have added this column as cross join into my data flow, and during preview it seems to have the value

[image: Data Preview]

But when I debug the pipeline, encountered following error :

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'TenantID', table 'dbo.Item'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.\njava.sql.BatchUpdateException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'TenantID', table 'dbo.Item'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.\n\tat
```

How to troubleshoot further to understand which row is returning null.I did a cross join, hence all valued should have been applied

Edit 1 : I tried exporting the same dataset into CSV, and true that none of the records had null TenantID.

[image: CSV Snaphot]

Comment: Are you trying to insert a unique number or just a '1' into each row for TenantID?

Are you anticipating that some rows will have NULLs for TenantID?

If you are using a Lookup or Join prior to this Sink, you can add a Conditional Split or a Filter to remove rows with NULL for TenantID. Or you can using IIF in a Derived Column to set a NULL TenantID to a dummy value.

Comment: I'm adding 1 based on parameter passed value. There shouldn't be any TenantID with Null since I'm doing a cross join. Tried adding the DERIVED step, yet same error.

Comment: The error being return by the DB driver indicates that some values you are sending to the sink are NULL. You should add a Filter transform before the sink to filter out those rows or IIF in a Derived Column to change NULL to a value.

Comment: @MarkKromer - as my previous comment - even after adding the check, I end up with same error. I tried publishing the record into csv file, but none was null.

Comment: Let's investigate this further. Can you send us a feedback request from the ADF UI? Click on the smiley face icon from the ADF browser UI and send us a request to  investigate.